# Если родитель с white-space: nowrap, как узнать ширину блока или самого родителя?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

В работе: https://jsfiddle.net/x_positive/a26dze9q/3/

Проблемный участок выглядит так:

```
    <div class="label">
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in finibus sapien, in blandit leo. Aliquam sit amet vulputate mi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed egestas et dui quis dictum. Donec facilisis nisl urna, quis consectetur odio lacinia non. Nam eu est lorem. Cras fermentum urna felis, et pharetra libero pulvinar quis. Phasellus vulputate at odio eget volutpat. Nam pretium, justo non ullamcorper luctus, sem nisi pulvinar sapien, ac maximus velit felis eu mi. Nullam sit amet diam eu erat finibus malesuada.</div>
    </div>
    <style>
        /* bootstrap.css:4047 */
        .label {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    </style>
```

Вся загвоздка в том, что пока текст не обернут в div, его ширина определяется корректно. Но когда он находится внутри обертки, то его ширина определяется как ширина body, когда текст вылазит за пределы блока.

Браузер (Chrome) отображает ширину блока идентично, заданной ширины, вместо реальной ширины текста, но добавляет полосу прокрутки. Имея у себя блок с белым текстом на белом фоне не мог найти его очень долго, вычисляя ширину объектов, которые могли бы создать горизонтальную полосу прокрутки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [`.scrollWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth).

```js
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.querySelector('.label div').scrollWidth + 'px';
```

```css
/* bootstrap.css:4047 */

.label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.max {
  width: 123px;
  max-width: 123px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.label {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.label div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

#result {
  margin-top: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.body_width_4_example {
  height: 1em;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="max">
  <div class="label">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in finibus sapien, in blandit leo. Aliquam sit amet vulputate mi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed egestas et dui quis dictum.
      Donec facilisis nisl urna, quis consectetur odio lacinia non. Nam eu est lorem. Cras fermentum urna felis, et pharetra libero pulvinar quis. Phasellus vulputate at odio eget volutpat. Nam pretium, justo non ullamcorper luctus, sem nisi pulvinar
      sapien, ac maximus velit felis eu mi. Nullam sit amet diam eu erat finibus malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in finibus sapien, in blandit leo. Aliquam sit amet vulputate mi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad
      litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed egestas et dui quis dictum. Donec facilisis nisl urna, quis consectetur odio lacinia non. Nam eu est lorem. Cras fermentum urna felis, et pharetra libero pulvinar quis. Phasellus vulputate
      at odio eget volutpat. Nam pretium, justo non ullamcorper luctus, sem nisi pulvinar sapien, ac maximus velit felis eu mi. Nullam sit amet diam eu erat finibus malesuada.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in finibus sapien,
      in blandit leo. Aliquam sit amet vulputate mi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed egestas et dui quis dictum. Donec facilisis nisl urna, quis consectetur odio lacinia non. Nam eu est lorem.
      Cras fermentum urna felis, et pharetra libero pulvinar quis. Phasellus vulputate at odio eget volutpat. Nam pretium, justo non ullamcorper luctus, sem nisi pulvinar sapien, ac maximus velit felis eu mi. Nullam sit amet diam eu erat finibus malesuada.Lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in finibus sapien, in blandit leo. Aliquam sit amet vulputate mi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed egestas et dui quis dictum.
      Donec facilisis nisl urna, quis consectetur odio lacinia non. Nam eu est lorem. Cras fermentum urna felis, et pharetra libero pulvinar quis. Phasellus vulputate at odio eget volutpat. Nam pretium, justo non ullamcorper luctus, sem nisi pulvinar
      sapien, ac maximus velit felis eu mi. Nullam sit amet diam eu erat finibus malesuada.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="body_width_4_example">Width of BODY for example
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте. Как я понял вы хотите остаток текста в блоке `.label` скрыть. Для этого используйте `overflow-x: hidden`. Если же вы хотите добавить полосу прокрутки к этому блоку, то используйте `overflow-x: auto`.

Comment: Не, я перебирал все элементы и получал их ширину, чтобы выяснить какой элемент создавал скролл у сайта, выяснилось что ширина у всех вписывалась в 320 при отображении на 320, хотя создавался скролл на порядок выше. Правильный ответ мне дали, document.querySelector('.label div').scrollWidth прекрасно справляется и поможет вычислить какой блок вылазит за пределы заданной ширины.